# Join table in Entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'll have this query in joining the table but it did not returned data from Include table or Join table.

```
var tasks = (from item in ctx.Tasks
             join tp in ctx.TaskPlugins
             on item.TaskId equals tp.TaskId
             select item)
              .Include(x => x.TaskPlugins).Include(x => x.TaskPlugins.Select(p => p.Plugin)).Include(x=>x.TaskPlugins.Select(p=>p.Plugin.Store));
return ctx.Tasks.ToList();
```

But this query does not return data from `TaskPlugins`
[image: screenshot]

Error Message: `((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Task_6F777A6C52D9E84FD3DF53481564A61969CE62ABBA9D985448F99BFB8A49A2D7)new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<oRouter.Model.Task>(task).Items[0]).TaskPlugins`

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is in your includes. The `.Include(x => x.TaskPlugins)` already should include the `Plugin` and `Plugin.Store`. So try the query without the 2 extra includes, and see if you get the right values.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL No, the first include can't get all the objects deep down.

Comment: Then for simplicity he could try using the string way of including: `.Include("TaskPlugins").Include("TaskPlugins.Plugin").Include(TaskPlugin.Plugin.Store");`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL The 3rd include requests for the 3rd level child and if you do that, I believe the parents would be automatically included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing, You should be returning `tasks.ToList()` and not `ctx.Tasks.ToList()`

Second, the last include `.Include(x=>x.TaskPlugins.Select(p=>p.Plugin.Store)` is the only one needed. First 2 includes are **NOT** needed.

Comment: I have already changed but then I've got this new error: Invalid column name 'Plugin_StoreId'. but StoreId is present in the Plugin table field and in the Plugin model

Comment: Invalid column name 'Plugin_StoreId'. but StoreId is present in the Plugin table field and in the Plugin model

Comment: I have figure it out. Thanks @sachin